# How to delete a specific component from project on sonar dashboard?

Tags: sonarqube

We want to remove a specific component from an project on sonar dashbaord. Is there any way to do that - maybe directly in the sonar database ? I could find only the deletion of whole project on sonar dashboard. The deletion of the component is needed as source code has to be protected and now it is visible to all see source code users of the project which is wrong.

sonar version 4.5.1

Comment: please provide the version of SonarQube you are using if you expect some help

Comment: Why not just remove it from the next Sonar analysis execution?

Answer (score 0):

You should [restrict code viewing permissions](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization).

If it's truly the case that you have users who should be able to see some components but not others then I would advise extracting the sensitive component(s) into another project on which you can impose tighter restrictions.